# Why is there a dot in front of .bashrc 

Tags: linux, bashrc

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now, pretty simple question for some I can only guess, but why is there a 'dot' in front of `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 5):

By default, filenames prefixed by a dot (.) don't show up when you do the ls command in Linux.*  Most system files (like `.bashrc`) are prefixed by a dot for this reason.

*Unless you run ls with the appropriate switches; **man ls** for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a hidden file.

Standard file browsers won't display files beginning with a `.` unless you set some setting for it ("Show hidden files" or similar). Files beginning with a `.` will also not appear on the standard `ls` output, but `ls -a` will allow you to see them.

It basically reduces clutter since hidden files a generally ones you won't need to see on a daily basis.